# How to extract content from a corrupted .docx file?

Tags: xml

I modified a `.docx` document using LibreOffice when I open it i get this error:

```
File format error found at 
SAXParseException: '[word/document.xml line 2]: Opening and ending tag mismatch: sdtContent line 0 and txbxContent
', Stream 'word/document.xml', Line 2, Column 9310(row,col)
```

Here is what I did:

1. right click on the document
2. extract here

Now I have a file that contains XML files it has all the content, I opened it with sublime text that doesn't highlight all XML which makes it hard to rebuild the content using copy/past.

My question is:

Is there a way to build a `.odt` document using this folder of XML files?